# Why am I getting java unknown host exception while posting json?

Tags: java, html, json, post

Here is my code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String path = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Jsons\\myfile.json";
String url = "http://file:///C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/myPage.html"; // Should I remove http:// ?
String json = readFile(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity jsonEntity = new StringEntity(json);
post.setEntity(jsonEntity);
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

System.out.println(response);
```

The `readFile()` method is here (which I got from another stackoverflow answer):

```
public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

I have a small html file called "myPage.html" which has a form which takes a json input and calls another site which generates another json file. If I open my html file in browser and paste the input json and hit submit, I am getting the output json. So the html works totally fine, however when I try to do this in java, it doesn't work. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: file
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at newTest.newDriver.main(newDriver.java:46)
```

I looked up on stackoverflow where I found that file string should have three forward slashes, but my file string already has that and yet this doesn't work.

Update #1:
If I do what you say, I get this exception now:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: C:/Users/Username/Desktop/myPage.html
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at newTest.newDriver.main(newDriver.java:46)
```

Update #2:
Here is my html file called `myPage.html`.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://backend.hera.potentiaco.com/simavg">
    <textarea name="s" cols="160" rows="40"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And my `myfile.json` has some gibberish in it like "sdfg". If I paste this content in the above html page and hit submit I get something like this:

```
{
    "error": "illegal value"
}
```

But I am unable to reproduce the same thing in my java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your url should be `String url = "C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/myPage.html";` change that and post your exception again

Comment: yes I did, but I still get an exception. I posted it in my question under Update.